# How to (programmatically) draw arrows between HTML table-entries?

Tags: html, tabular

[image: table with arrow]

Given a standard static HTML-table, what is the most simple way to, programmatically, to draw an arrow between any two HTML-table entries? See above picture for an example.

I know that the HTML5-canvas can be used to draw graphics, but I am hoping for a simpler/easier way to achieve this.

UPDATE: I am not bound to HTML-tables. If needed, the tables can be generated in any format that can read by a web-browser.

Comment: I'm not sure but You can try `.svg` it sholud work better than `canvas`. As I know You can put some `id's` to Your cells and then use JavaScript to draw an arrow between those cells using `svg` image

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the use of the identifiers in the table-cells? Are they part of the HTML-language?

Comment: Yes You can use something like `...<td id="arrowFrom">cell content</td>...<td id="arrowTo">cell content</div>...` After that. You can use JavaScript to find those elements, and made `svg` image from center of one to center of another cell. Then use JavaScript to posiotion image to it place (using inline img css styles). It's complicated but it works (but not on every brovser:( )

Comment: I guess my question comes down to: how to do draw an arrow between two html-objects corresponding to two hmtl-identifiers? These seems like a quite standard wish. Isn't there an of the shelf available library available for doing so?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't heard about. But if You don't need dynamic solution You can use @arkascha answer from bellow. It's not full answer, but if You know css then You should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, in that I want to draw arrows between cells in different tables, but I think the answer I'm resigned to will likely work for you: SVG. If you're auto-generating this from a data structure that has the column/row layout configured, and you can determine the row heights and column widths that you need, you should be able to generate the co-ordinates for the lines to do whatever you want over the text.

```html
<svg width="300" height="100">
    <text x='100' y='0' font-size='18px' text-anchor='end'>
      <tspan x='100' dy='1em'>foo1</tspan>
      <tspan x='100' dy='1em'>foo2</tspan>
      <tspan x='100' dy='1em'>foo3</tspan>
    </text>

    <text x='200 y='0' font-size='18px'>
      <tspan x='200' dy='1em'>foo4</tspan>
      <tspan x='200' dy='1em'>foo5</tspan>
      <tspan x='200' dy='1em'>foo6</tspan>
    </text>

    <line x1='100' y1='0.8em' x2='200' y2='2.8em' style="stroke:#999999"/>
    <line x1='100' y1='1.8em' x2='200' y2='1.8em' style="stroke:#999999"/>
    <line x1='100' y1='1.8em' x2='200' y2='0.8em' style="stroke:#ff0000"/>
    <line x1='100' y1='0.8em' x2='200' y2='1.8em' style="stroke:#ff0000"/>
    <line x1='100' y1='2.8em' x2='200' y2='2.8em' style="stroke:#00ff00"/>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare an image of an arrow. You include it into the page into the same container (typically `div` or `span` tag) that holds the table itself. That container is marked as using an `absolute` positioning inside the css definitions. For your array image you specify a `relative` positioning. Now you can adjust the position to get the array flowt exactly where you want it to. you might have to specify a z-index for the array too.

This however has some issues with the angle of the arrow. Obviously you can strech and bend it using css width and height attributes, but you cannot turn it. At least not as far as I know. If you need an array you can turn freely, for example if you visualize the arrow dynamically by a script code, then you might prefer one of these approaches:

1. there are jquery extensions that offer to draw on a canvas
2. create the arrow image as a vector graphic (SVG format). That format can embed scripts for interactivity. That way you can turn and otherwise interact with the array on a script level.

Comment: It's simply but only if the position of cells does not change. If it will change, or You want to use it in different tables it should be dynamic.